# Count entities in multiple tables

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jpql

I Have a non-entity class

```
public class CountryStatistics {

    public CountryStatistics(Long numTowns, Long numVillages) {
    ...
    }

}
```

For a given country i want to construct a statistics object.

Country, Village and City are the Entitys, so i tried things in line with code below.

```
String queryString = 
"SELECT NEW mypackage.CountryStatistics(count(t), count(v)) 
 FROM Town t, Village v WHERE t.country = :country AND v.country = :country"

TypedQuery<CountryStatistics> query = 
em.createQuery(queryString ,CountryStatistics.class).setParameter("country", country);

query.getSingleResult()
```

Question: What is the correct way to count some entities in different tables in the same query?

With the above query i end up with way to high numbers if i put distinct like below, number of towns will be correct.

```
"SELECT NEW mypackage.CountryStatistics(count(distinct t), count(v)) 
 FROM Town t, Village v WHERE t.country = :country AND v.country = :country"
```

But if I set it for villages also i get:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Multiple DISTINCT aggregates are not supported at this time.
```

Comment: You're not saying what the problem is.

Comment: Ah true, added some further explanation

Comment: It looks like your database doesn't support multiple distinct aggregates. Which database is it? PostgreSQL supports that just fine.

Comment: It's the JavaDB that comes with glassfish

Comment: Try with a real database.

Answer (score 2):

The following query (not tested) should do what you want:

```
select count(distinct t.id), count(distinct v.id) from Country c
left join c.towns t
left join c.villages v
where c.id = :countryId
```

Comment: In my scenario Country doesnt have property .towns

Comment: The query in your updated questions, with two distinct clauses, should work fine. It looks like a limitation of your database.